# Fatal Exception:UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency child viewcntrler<AVFullScreenPlaybackControlsViewController:should have parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime-error, avkit

I am facing below crash in my live app. Posting here the crash report from Crashlytics. Can you please guide me regarding this.

```
Fatal Exception: UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency child view controller:<AVFullScreenPlaybackControlsViewController:> should have parent view controller:<MyAVPlayerViewController:> but actual parent is:<AVFullScreenViewController:>

Fatal Exception: UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency



Fatal Exception: UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency
    0  CoreFoundation                 0x181616db0 __exceptionPreprocess
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180c7bf80 objc_exception_throw
    2  CoreFoundation                 0x181616cf8 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
    3  UIKit                          0x1867f5010 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _associatedViewControllerForwardsAppearanceCallbacks:performHierarchyCheck:isRoot:]
    4  UIKit                          0x18677cdbc -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:]
    5  UIKit                          0x18677c13c -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
    6  AVKit                          0x18cab3860 -[AVPlayerViewController _updatePlaybackControlsViewController]
    7  AVKit                          0x18cab20e4 -[AVPlayerViewController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]
    8  Foundation                     0x181f37d84 -[NSKeyValueObservance observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]
    9  Foundation                     0x181f13f64 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver
    10 Foundation                     0x181f13a8c NSKeyValueDidChange
    11 Foundation                     0x181efe624 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:]
    12 AVKit                          0x18caac54c -[AVPlayerView _updateViewWindowState]
    13 AVKit                          0x18caac358 -[AVPlayerView setFrame:]
    14 UIKit                          0x18678c38c -[UIView(Geometry) _applyAutoresizingMaskWithOldSuperviewSize:]
    15 CoreFoundation                 0x181507944 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke
    16 CoreFoundation                 0x18150783c -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
    17 UIKit                          0x18677aa74 -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:]
    18 UIKit                          0x18676c6c8 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:]
    19 UIKit                          0x18692044c -[UIViewController window:statusBarWillChangeFromHeight:toHeight:windowSizedViewController:]
    20 UIKit                          0x18691feb8 -[UIViewController window:statusBarWillChangeFromHeight:toHeight:]
    21 UIKit                          0x1868b1e84 -[UIWindow handleStatusBarChangeFromHeight:toHeight:]
    22 UIKit                          0x186809b4c +[UIWindow _noteStatusBarHeightChanged:oldHeight:forAutolayoutRootViewsOnly:]
    23 UIKit                          0x186920910 __79-[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:]_block_invoke
    24 UIKit                          0x1867acfa8 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
    25 UIKit                          0x1868ffd1c +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:completion:]
    26 UIKit                          0x186836e50 -[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:]
    27 UIKit                          0x18677bdb0 -[UIApplication _updateCurrentStatusBarViewControllerAppearance]
    28 UIKit                          0x1867eebb8 -[UIViewController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]
    29 UIKit                          0x1867eeb2c -[UIViewController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]
    30 UIKit                          0x1868788c0 -[UIViewController _setPresentedStatusBarViewController:]
    31 UIKit                          0x186af54ac -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:]
    32 UIKit                          0x186af6e54 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:]
    33 UIKit                          0x186af9890 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:]
    34 UIKit                          0x18686f3cc -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
    35 AVKit                          0x18cab4b08 -[AVPlayerViewController _transitionToFullScreenViewControllerAnimated:completionHandler:]
    36 AVKit                          0x18cab7198 -[AVPlayerViewController(AVPlaybackControlsViewControllerActions) fullScreenButtonTapped:]
    37 AVKit                          0x18cadb0cc -[AVPlaybackControlsViewController fullScreenButtonTapped:]
    38 UIKit                          0x1867acbe8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
    39 UIKit                          0x1867acb64 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
    40 UIKit                          0x186794870 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
    41 UIKit                          0x1867ac454 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
    42 UIKit                          0x1867ac084 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
    43 UIKit                          0x1867a4c20 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
    44 UIKit                          0x18677504c -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
    45 UIKit                          0x186773628 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
    46 CoreFoundation                 0x1815cd09c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    47 CoreFoundation                 0x1815ccb30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    48 CoreFoundation                 0x1815ca830 __CFRunLoopRun
    49 CoreFoundation                 0x1814f4c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    50 GraphicsServices               0x182ddc088 GSEventRunModal
    51 UIKit                          0x1867de088 UIApplicationMain
    52 VideoCutterMerger              0x100021724 main (main.m:13)
    53 libdispatch.dylib              0x1810928b8 (Missing)
```

.

Comment: I'm also seeing reports of this crash in the wild, but I'm unable to reproduce the issue myself. Do you know how to reproduce it and/or did you come up with a solution?

Comment: This seems related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203119/avplayer-crash-when-resizing-window-during-fullscreen-while-hotspotting.